# Pavlova trypophobia

Tags: baking

I just finished baking my third pavlova and it seems fine except that there's a strange circular pattern covering the exterior which is triggering my [trypophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypophobia)!

Does anyone have any tips on how to avoid?

Comment: I was trypophobic too until I tried it Korean style.  Delicious!

Comment: Is it weeping sugar? It can look like beading.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flat metal object to smooth the edges before it fully sets. Wet the metal object with water first.